# I have an html file with multiple urls. I want to dynamically change the version number in the url thru shell script

Tags: shell-script, html

I am a novice in shell scripting. Need help!!

I have a html file with multiple urls like https://test.abc.net/xxx/**999994236**/styles/css/the-guide-styles-responsive.min.css

I want to create a shell script in which I can pass a new version number which will replace the existing version number (shown in BOLD) in all the such urls.

This is what I have done till now taking just one url as of now;

```
#!/bin/bash

version=$1 ##Taking version as a parameter
my_str="https://test.abc.net/xxx/**999994236**/styles/css/the-guide-styles-responsive.min.css"
IFS='/' #setting slash as delimiter
read -a strarr <<<"$my_str" #reading str as an array as tokens separated by IFS
echo "Version : ${strarr[4]} "
strarr[4]=$1
echo "Version : ${strarr[4]} "
SAVE_IFS="$IFS"
IFS="/"
my_str_join="${my_str[*]}"
IFS="$SAVE_IFS"
echo "$my_str_join"

my_str_new="https://test.abc.net/xxx/**${strarr[4]}**/styles/css/the-guide-styles-responsive.min.css"
SAVE_IFS="$IFS"
IFS="/"
my_str_new_join="${my_str_new[*]}"
IFS="$SAVE_IFS"
echo "$my_str_new_join"

sed -i 's~${my_str_join}~${my_str_new_join}~g' index1.html ##This is where I am stuck.
```

If I put actual urls in place of variables *${my_str_join}* & *${my_str_new_join}*, this step works fine but with variables it doesn't.

I have tried everything and can't brainstorm anymore. How should I go ahead with this? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sed-command

```
sed -i 's~${my_str_join}~${my_str_new_join}~g' index1.html
```

uses single-quotes, which prevent substitution.  Use double-quotes where you intend substitution, e.g.,

```
sed -i 's~${my_str_join}~'"${my_str_new_join}"'~g' index1.html
```

Comment: It worked!. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer was useful, you could mark it accepted.

Comment: Done! Can someone tell if the approach I am following is correct or a better short way is possible? I basically need to do the above with all the urls available in the html file. I am trying to fetch all the urls available in html file and save them in an array and then loop thru that array.

Comment: I'd use some tool (such as "lynx -dump") to get the urls, and construct a sed script using those (e.g., a text-file) and use sed.  A loop would be far slower.